# Add custom text before all image captions in WordPress posts

Tags: functions, images, captions

I add captions to images in WordPress using the "Caption" box to indicate the photographer's name.

I need custom text to always be displayed before the image caption,

That is, now I just have “text”, but I need it to become like this: “Photo: text”. This must be done for all image captions in WP posts.

The caption code for the images in the article now looks like this:

```
<p id="caption-attachment-00001 class="wp-caption-text">Image caption</p>
```

How can i do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the image caption using the [`wp_get_attachment_caption`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_caption/) filter:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_caption', 'wpse422651_filter_image_caption', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Filters the image caption.
 *
 * @param  string $caption       The image caption.
 * @param  int    $attachment_id The attachment ID.
 * @return string                The filtered caption.
 */
function wpse422651_filter_image_caption( $caption, $attachment_id ) {
  // Only run if the caption isn't empty and the attachment is an image.
  if ( ! empty( $caption ) && wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment_id ) ) {
    return 'Photo: ' . $caption;
  }
}
```

### References

- [`wp_get_attachment_caption` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_caption/)
- [`wp_attachment_is_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_attachment_is_image/)

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately this doesn't work for me (((
I don't notice any changes to the image captions in the posts.

Of course I cleared the cache.

Comment: Your code worked for thumbnails (featured post image). I display them using the code <?php the_post_thumbnail_caption(); ?> But your code does not affect the images that are inside the post content.

Comment: Sounds like I've got the wrong filter here. I'll see what I can find a little later.